# How to solidify the bow of a boat in blender evenly?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, solidify-modifier

I have completed a model of a boat, but I'm encountering difficulty solidifying it.

While scaling worked well for most of the boat, the front end is problematic, where it's becoming pointed.
[image: boat with tickness]
The bow's walls are intersecting, and ideally, the front of the boat should have a smoothly pointed and smoothed-out appearance, like a roof.
[image]
I've consulted numerous experts, but none have been able to provide a solution. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Sincerely,
Matej L.

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: If you are trying to solidify "outwards", and it's protruding through itself, it could be because of incorrect normal direction. Select the whole mesh in edit mode and press Shift+N (recalculate normals outside), then try the solidify again.

Comment: Hello, Mat... at first sight, _Solidify_ should work.. so can you share a representative chunk on https://blend-exchange.com/ so we can see what's up, if @ChristopherBennett isn't onto it?